# Make python simulated keypress work with remapped key in Windows

Tags: python, pyautogui, keystroke, directinput

I have recently installed SharpKeys. It allows to remap keys in Windows.
For example, if I use any type of key simulation in python:

`pydirectinput.press('f12')//I had already mapped f12 in sharpkeys to other key's functionality`

It just clicks f12, how can I achieve that if I'm using pydirectinput or other libraries to send a specified key it goes through the previous SharpKeys remapped keys.

What I am trying to do:

send key input in python (for example f12) --> SharpKeys receives it --> SharpKeys interprets it and performs the key that is actually assigned to the key input that was performed in python (converts f12 that I had remapped earlier to "Q" key)

I tried using pydirectinput, pyautogui.

I also found out about the interception library for python but it doesn't work for me. I guess that it would also solve my problem, but unfortunately doesn't work, tho.